# S3 bucket policy that limits access by IP not working behind CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CloudFront distribution setup that forwards traffic to an s3 bucket. That bucket has a policy attached to it, that denies access to certain resources based on the source (client) IP address. Policy works ok when s3 is accessed directly, but when request is going through CloudFront it's no longer respected.

Is there a way to solve this?

Current S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1620712955196",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BlockGifs",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mytestbucket/*.gif",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "39.111.102.19/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The IP used will be that of CloudFront, not yours. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why are you using CloudFront if you only want the content accessed by a single IP address?

Comment: @Marcin limit access to GIFs (for example) to only clients from office IP.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein because that bucket contains many other files, not only those that I want to restrict access too. Imagine this is a bucket for JS files and sourcemaps -- sourcemaps should only be accessible by certain people, while JS files are public.

Answer (score 1):

[OAI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) will restrict only cloudfront to retrieving it.

[lambda@edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) will be able to handle the restrictions based on headers.